# Python setdiff1d is wotking but union1d is not working for the same data

Tags: python, numpy

I have two python list A,B. The data for A & B are following

```
 A=[[1733017],
 [1735419],
 [1736910],
 [1741262],
 [1742027],
 [1750888],
 [1752145],
 [1752928],
 [1756128]]
B=[[1733017],
 [1735419],
 [1756910],
 [1741262]]
```

I want to do set difference & union between these two lists. So I tried

```
z=np.setdiff1d(a,b)
z=np.union1d(a,b)
```

setdiff1d is working properly but for union1d I got following error message

```
ValueError: all the input array dimensions except for the concatenation axis must match exactly
```

Can you suggest what modification I need to do in python 3.x?

Comment: Can't reproduce, this works for me on 1.13.3. Try upgrading your numpy version?

Comment: I also have version 1.13.3. The data I share is sample of my encoded data. Can't able to share the original data. .len(a) is returning 12829 & len(b) is 124986. Isn't it possible for you to tell based on error message?

Comment: Not unless I have more information. For example, what is `a.shape` and `b.shape`?

Comment: This is seemingly not the example you used, given the A-a/B-b differences. Do you get the same error message with this very same example you posted here?

Answer (score 1):

`numpy.union1d` first concatenates its arguments using `numpy.concatenate`, and then performs the union operation by calling `numpy.unique` on the concatenated arrays.  Here's the complete function:

```
def union1d(ar1, ar2):
    return unique(np.concatenate((ar1, ar2)))
```

You'll get the error that you reported if the arguments are not compatible with `numpy.concatenate`.  For example, here are the sample variables that you gave:

```
In [18]: A
Out[18]: 
[[1733017],
 [1735419],
 [1736910],
 [1741262],
 [1742027],
 [1750888],
 [1752145],
 [1752928],
 [1756128]]

In [19]: B
Out[19]: [[1733017], [1735419], [1756910], [1741262]]
```

Both are "array-like": `A` has shape (9, 1), and `B` has shape (4, 1).  These shapes are compatible for concatenation:

```
In [21]: np.concatenate((A, B))
Out[21]: 
array([[1733017],
       [1735419],
       [1736910],
       [1741262],
       [1742027],
       [1750888],
       [1752145],
       [1752928],
       [1756128],
       [1733017],
       [1735419],
       [1756910],
       [1741262]])
```

And `numpy.union1d(A, B)` works:

```
In [22]: np.union1d(A, B)
Out[22]: 
array([1733017, 1735419, 1736910, 1741262, 1742027, 1750888, 1752145,
       1752928, 1756128, 1756910])
```

Here's what happens if the shape of the second argument is changed to (4,) by passing in `np.array(B).flatten()` instead of `B`:

```
In [23]: np.union1d(A, np.array(B).flatten())
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-d081803e0f7e> in <module>()
----> 1 np.union1d(A, np.array(B).flatten())

<...>/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/lib/arraysetops.py in union1d(ar1, ar2)
    612     array([1, 2, 3, 4, 6])
    613     """
--> 614     return unique(np.concatenate((ar1, ar2)))
    615 
    616 def setdiff1d(ar1, ar2, assume_unique=False):

ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions
```

That error is being generated by `numpy.concatenate`:

```
In [24]: np.concatenate((A, np.array(B).flatten()))
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-24-9795b4f89edc> in <module>()
----> 1 np.concatenate((A, np.array(B).flatten()))

ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions
```

To fix the problem, you have to ensure that the arguments are compatible for concatenation.  One way to do this is to ensure that the arguments passed to `numpy.union1d` are both flattened into one-dimensional arrays:

```
In [26]: np.union1d(np.array(A).flatten(), np.array(B).flatten())
Out[26]: 
array([1733017, 1735419, 1736910, 1741262, 1742027, 1750888, 1752145,
       1752928, 1756128, 1756910])
```

---

P.S.  This appears to be a bug in `numpy.union1d`.  In the description of the arguments, it says "They are flattened if they are not already 1D", so you shouldn't have to worry about the shape of the inputs.  I reported the bug here: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/10340

Comment: Thank you @Warren. for the detail explanation & the way to fix the problem. I will try this

Comment: FYI: A fix for the bug has been [merged in numpy's master branch](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/pull/10342) and will be in the next numpy release.